# Checking if a Page has an Associated Term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, conditional-content, terms

I am looking for a way to do some conditional logic on terms associated with a post.

Essentially I created my own custom taxonomy for "age groups" and have created three terms for them. Kids, Teens, Adults... In the admin area I want to check the terms which apply to a specific post and on the frontend of the site within my page template I want to show a specific image if the term was associated with the post or a different one if the term was not associated.

Does anyone have a solution for this... I thought the following code example would work but it does not. (BTW - what I am doing here is changing the image based off css).

```
<li id="kids-<?php if ( is_term( 'Kids' , 'age_groups' ) ) {
   echo 'on';
} else {echo 'off';} ?>">Kids Programs</li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi **@NetConstructor:**

First thing, *assuming* your logic worked you can use the ternary operator to simplify your example:

```
<li id="kids-<?php echo is_term('Kids','age_groups') 
   ? 'on' : 'off'; ?>">Kids Programs</li>
```

The issue seems to be that `is_term()` is used to check if a term exists, not if it is associated with a particular post. I think what you really want is `is_object_in_term()` *(which assumes that you are in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), i.e. that `$post` has an appropriate value):*

```
<li id="kids-<?php echo is_object_in_term($post->ID,'age_groups','Kids') 
   ? 'on' : 'off'; ?>">Kids Programs</li>
```

P.S. Assuming `is_term()` had been the right function, it has actually been [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Deprecated_Functions_Hook); `term_exists()` replaces `is_term()`; just fyi.

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thanks!.... I knew there must have been a simple solution for what I was looking for.

Comment: @NetConstructor - Glad it helped!